# Manually created view in ViewHolder created in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I would like to make generic adapter which let me reuse it. That's why I decided to not to create view by `inflating`, but pass custom, previously created view to `ViewHolder` in `ListAdapter` (`RecyclerView`) in `onCreateViewHolder`. According to its documentation it should be possible, because it says:

> You can either create a new View **manually** or inflate it from an XML layout file.

This is my adapter implementation:

```
class BaseAdapter<T, V : View>(
        private val adapterConfig: AdapterConfig<T, V>,
        private val onClick: (T) -> (Unit)
) : ListAdapter<T, BaseViewHolder<V>>(adapterConfig.diffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<V> {
        return adapterConfig.viewHolder.apply {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { onClick(getItem(adapterPosition)) }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<V>, position: Int) {
        adapterConfig.bind(getItem(position), holder, position)
    }
}
```

`AdapterConfig` implementation class is reposnible for creating `ViewHolder` and it's looks like this:

```
override val viewHolder: BaseViewHolder<ScorerView> = BaseViewHolder(ScorerView(context))
```

`BaseViewHolder` class:

```
class BaseViewHolder<out V : View>(val v: V) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v)
```

(Nothing interesting until now)

My `ScorerView` is:

```
class ScorerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_ranking, this, false)
    }

    fun configure(id: String, player: String, team: String, matchSet: String, points: String, pointsAvg: String) {
        idTextView.text = id
        playerTextView.text = player
        teamTextView.text = team
        matchSetTextView.text = matchSet
        pointsTextView.text = points
        pointsAvgTextView.text = pointsAvg
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I pass `false` to `inflate` function (which is ok, because `RecyclerView` require to item view wasn't attached to root view) then my widget instances (`idTextView` for example) is null. Otherwise when I manually attach view to root either by passing `true` or by calling `addView(view)` I'm getting a crash saying that view can't be attached when created:

> ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)

My question is: is it even possible? If not, why official documentation saying that it's possible to manually create view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning the same view over and over again. It is an explicit requirement that `onCreateViewHolder()` **creates a new view** every time it is invoked.

The documentation says that you can create the View manually, but that still means that you manually create a different view each time `onCreateViewHolder()` runs.

So, because you're re-using the same view every time, the *second* time your app calls `onCreateViewHolder()`, the view is already attached to the parent.

Comment: Thank you for response. You are right that I'm returnin the same object over and over again. I got in to notation trap. Unfortunately it not solve my problem, because widgets are still null in the first `onBindViewHolder` call. I would like to add that my `ScorerView` class is not a problem, because when I create it manually in Fragment with `attachToRoot = false` then I get a crash with null widget, but when I set this parameter to `true` then everything is ok and I can use it normaly.

Comment: When you inflate a view in `onCreateViewHolder()`, and then pass it to a ViewHolder constructor, it's ok to pass `false` for `attachToRoot` because the recycler view will do the attaching for you. In the code you posted `init { LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_ranking, this, false) }` this view is just getting thrown out because you don't manually do any attaching of it to anything.

Comment: Actually I don't understand that, but I passed `attachToRoot = true` and now it's working. Meanwhile doing some code cleanups I changed my `.xml` file name, so I guess there had to be something with the IDE, but I actually don't know what. I spent on this problem good amount of time, so it's pretty frustrating.. Anyway many thanks for your answer, I will accept it, because in fact you found a bug in my code :)